# Toyota dies when I turn on the AC

Tags: engine, toyota, ac, tercel

Hello I have a 1994 Toyota Terrel and I'm experincing some problems that have me stumped.

The car will die now when the AC is turned on. Gives out a weird cry and starts to die. A week ago it was just fine. At first I thought it was the alternator but I tried driving it around with all the lights on at once and while playing  the radio and had no issues. I sprinted car with music for a while and nothing.

the problem only occurs when the AC is tuned on. The car currently doesn't have a band for the AC nor does it have the air, but hasn't for a long time. It currently does have dark oil. I don't know if that could have something to do with it. Has full oil, water and gas. I'm hoping someone  know what's wrong because I have no idea.

- Does anyone know what might be causing this?
- Could this be due to the lack of a belt?
- Would the fan operation be a separate problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're saying there's no fan belt connecting the AC compressor to the engine?

Comment: Yes.but its been like that for years really

Comment: OK, I'll bite...Why would you turn the AC on if it knowingly doesn't work and causes this issue. Unless you are in process of repairing the AC, it seems the easy solution is not to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

Your oil has nothing to do with the AC circuit. When you push the button inside your car it throws an electro magnetic clutch in the pump engaging it to compress the refrigerant. The circuit may be damaged. Try checking for a short to ground.

Comment: So are you saying the ground wire connected to the battery might be damaged? Is that the one I should check?    Sorry I don't know much about cars.I'm learning as I go through problems

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the earths between engine and body / battery - if the engine is using the ac earth to run - when you switch on the ac it can kill the engine

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that your belt is connected to the a/c compressor because that would be the only way for your vehicle to be drug down on power and squeal like a alternator belt , I would check that over again and if the belts still attached cut the belt off or Lord if your lucky tightening the belt my help but if not cut the belt until you have time to replace your compressor ,dryer/accumulator , expansion valve and make sure you flush your system extremely well because it sounds like your system is contaminated which in turn contaminates the compressor oil , I've saved a lot of people from spending unecessary money in the past and if you are close enough to me I would sure help you out or you could call me and I could give you a couple of short cuts to try before contaminating the system !!!  352-442-6679 anytime !!!

Answer (score -1):

If The car doesn’t die as you were driving down the street and turn on the AC, but does die when you first start the car with a/c on, This is most likely the idle air control valve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).